# What is the probability of guessing all the Oscar winners?

Tags: probability

I was wondering about the probability of someone guessing all of the Oscar's winners.

There are 24 categories. The number of movies per category may vary but we can assume a mean of 6 movies per category.

So, would this mean that the probability of guessing all winners would be:
$\dfrac{1}{24\cdot 6}$??

Comment: I believe this implies that each movie has an equal chance of winning, which may or may not be the case. :-)

Comment: moreover you know leonardo wont win

Comment: @walkar this is about the probability of one's guessing the result, so the changes of winning do not matter.

Comment: @Vetras Not quite, because if the result is decided beforehand that movies $A$, $B$, and $C$ in category $1$ are irrelevant and will not be chosen no matter what and movies $D$, $E$, and $F$ have an equal probability of winning, then picking $A$, $B$, or $C$ will give you a $0$ percent chance to win whereas picking the $D$, $E$, or $F$ will give you a $\frac{1}{3}$ chance of winning. You really do have to make the assumption that each movie has an equal chance to win or else the probabilities change.

Comment: @walkar That depends on how you make your guesses. If your picks are arbitrary, then it makes no difference.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you assume that each movie is equally likely to be chosen, then the probability of guessing the correct chosen movie in any given category is $ \frac {1} {\text{# of movies}} = \frac 1 6 $.
Then because we have 24 different categories, and furthermore, we assume that the probability of a movie winning in one category is independent of the other movies, then

$
Pr(\text{guess all categories}) = Pr(\text{guess movie in cat-1},\text{guess movie in cat-2},\text{guess movie in cat-3},\text{guess movie in cat-4},\text{guess movie in cat-5},\text{guess movie in cat-6},...,\text{guess movie in cat-24}) \\ \ = (\frac 1 6)(\frac 1 6)(\frac 1 6)(\frac 1 6)(\frac 1 6)(\frac 1 6).... (\frac 1 6) = \frac 1 {6^{24}}
$

Just note that we made two assumptions: .1. equal distribution of winning .2. independence of categories

Answer (score 3):

Presuming each of the twenty-four categories is chosen independently, and each category has six choices, there will be, in total, $\dfrac{1}{6^{24}}$ chance of guessing all categories correctly, which is a very small number, not $\dfrac{1}{24\cdot 6}$.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that each movie has an equal chance of winning and there are exactly 6 movies in each category, the probability of guessing all of them correctly would be

$\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)^{24}\approx2*10^{-19}$